# Add readonly field upon editing in ApostropheCMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms, tom

I want to make a particular field readonly when i edit some field.

```
module.exports = {
 extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
 name: xyz,
 label: xyz,
 addFields: [{
  nameL: 'latitude',
  lable: 'latitude',
  type: 'string',
  required: true
 }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want and what the snippet is supposed to be for

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `readOnly: true` to the definition of your field:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: xyz,
  label: xyz,
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'latitude',
      label: 'latitude',
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      readOnly: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This field is also readOnly when i want to enter data. can you please tell me it should only show as a readOnly when i edit some data?

Comment: You are asking for a different feature that does not exist. You could open a github issue suggesting it.